# Как работает деструктор

Tags: c++

Объясните, что именно освобождает память при вызове деструктора для объекта, ведь по умолчанию он имеет пустое тело.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

1. Формально деструктор не имеет никакого отношения к освобождению памяти "своего" объекта. Освобождение памяти делается внешним кодом, который и вызывает деструктор перед освобождением. Поэтому с этой точки зрения ваш вопрос несколько бессмыслен.
2. Деструктор - специальная функция. Даже если он имеет пустое тело, совсем не означает, что "ничего не делает". Например, деструктор всегда *неявно* вызывает деструкторы подобъектов данного класса, даже если у него внешне "пустое" тело.

   Понятно, что деструктор может быть ответственен за явное освобождение посторонних ресурсов, которыми напрямую владеет ваш объект (в том числе память). Но в этом случае и тело деструктора не будет пустым.
3. В "традиционных" реализациях, как ни странно, когда деструктор виртуален, функция освобождения динамической памяти объекта зачастую неявно вызывается *изнутри* деструктора (а не наружным кодом). Такой трюк необходим для того, чтобы обеспечить правильное поведение перегруженного `operator delete` для класса (если таковой имеется). Но это уже внутренние детали реализации.

---

Третий пункт ссылается на следующую ситуацию.

В языке С++ абстрактный алгоритм работы оператора `delete` сводится к последовательности из двух шагов:

1. Вызов правильного деструктора объекта
2. Вызов правильной функции освобождения "сырой" памяти `operator delete(void *)`.

Функция `operator delete(void *)`, как известно, может замещаться/перегружаться пользователем. Разрешается как замещать глобальный `::operator delete(void *)`, так и перегружать статическую функцию `operator delete(void *)` в конкретных классах. При этом спецификация языка требует, чтобы выбор конкретного `operator delete(void *)` делался так, как будто его поиск (name lookup) делался *из деструктора* удаляемого объекта.

Например

```
#include <iostream>

struct B
{
  virtual ~B()
  { 
    std::cout << "B::~B" << std::endl; 
  }
  
  void operator delete(void *p)
  { 
    std::cout << "B::operator delete" << std::endl;
    ::operator delete(p);
  }
};

struct D : B
{
  virtual ~D()
  { 
    std::cout << "D::~D" << std::endl; 
  }
  
  void operator delete(void *p)
  { 
    std::cout << "D::operator delete" << std::endl;
    ::operator delete(p);
  }
};

int main()
{
  B* pb = new B;
  B* pd = new D;
  delete pb;
  delete pd;
}
```

в таком коде при выполнении `delete pb` после выполнения деструктора `B::~B` должен вызваться `B::operator delete`, а при выполнении `delete pd` после выполнения деструктора `D::~D` должен вызваться `D::operator delete`. Другими словами, несмотря на то, что функция `operator delete` всегда является *статическим* членом класса, она должна вести себя фактически как *виртуальная* (!) функция.

Для того, чтобы удовлетворить этому требованию языка, большинство реализаций просто-напросто переносят вызов правильного `operator delete` внутрь деструктора. Таким образом требуемая "виртуальность" функции `operator delete` достигается бесплатно, за счет виртуальности деструктора.

При этом понятно, что `operator delete(void *)` нужно вызвать только для полных объектов, размещенных в динамической памяти, а для остальных объектов - не нужно (т.е. нельзя). Чтобы принять это во внимание, компиляторы снабжают деструктор неявным булевским параметром, говорящим деструктору, надо ли вызывать `operator delete`. Таким образом в вышеприведенном примере деструкторы на самом деле будут иметь следующий вид

```
  B::~B(bool call_delete)               // неявный параметр
  { 
    std::cout << "B::~B" << std::endl; 

    if (call_delete)                    // неявно
      B::operator delete(this);         // неявно
  }

  ~D::D(bool call_delete)               // неявный параметр
  { 
    std::cout << "D::~D" << std::endl; 

    B::~B(false);                       // неявно

    if (call_delete)                    // неявно
      D::operator delete(this);         // неявно
  }
```

Выражения `delete pb` и `delete pd` в такой ситуации превращаются просто в виртуальные вызовы `pb->~B(true)` и `pd->~B(true)`. Первое попадает в `B::~B`, второе - в `D::~D`.

Компилятор GCC, кстати, в более ранних версиях реализовывал этот подход именно так, как описано выше - через скрытый булевский параметр, а в современных версиях этот же поход он реализует через генерацию двух отдельных деструкторов.

Answer (score 1):

Стандарт языка грантирует, что после тела деструктора (даже пустого) память будет освобождена. Автоматом.

Comment: Так а как это "автоматом" происходит?

Comment: Это уже личное дело компилятора. Удаляются в порядке объявления поля класса.