# Деструкция неинициализированных локальных статических переменных

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, storage

[Здесь](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration#Static_local_variables) сказано, что статические локальные переменные не инициализируются, если инициализация выбрасывает исключение:

> If the initialization throws an exception, the variable is not
>   considered to be initialized, and initialization will be attempted
>   again the next time control passes through the declaration.

Далее сказано, что деструктор таких переменных вызывается только в случае их успешной инициализации:

> The destructor for a block-scope static variable is called at program
>   exit, but only if the initialization took place successfully.

Правильно ли я понимаю, что если инициализация локальных статических переменных выбрасывает исключение для всех попыток инициализации, то память в начале старта программы для них будет выделена (т.к. они имеют статическое время жизни), однако освобождена не будет (т.к. деструктор не вызывается)?

Comment: Статические переменные располагаются как правило в сегменте BSS. Память для них резервируется в момент старта программы (процесса) один раз до отработки статического конструктора, а освобождается в момент прекращения существования процесса, а не после отработки статического деструктора.

Comment: @nick_n_a разве деструктор не должен быть вызван до освобождения памяти?

Comment: Есть разница между (динамическим) деструктором, и статическим деструктором. Статический деструктор ведет себя так как написано в описании. Компилятор делает разные вызовы (действия) на разные виды деструкторов.

Comment: *разве деструктор не должен быть вызван до освобождения памяти* - а я не говорил обратного. Он будет вызан до освобождения (при условии описаном).

Comment: если инициализация локальных статических переменных выбрасывает исключение для всех попыток инициализации, то обьект не будет создан, и говорить об освобождении памяти не приходится

Comment: @ARHovsepyan думаю, что создан (выделена память) он будет в начале программы в любом случае, а вот **проинициализирован** не будет

Comment: @cppforlife, ну хорошо, посмотрим это на примере.

Answer (score 1):

Деструктор не освобождает память, поэтому всё освободится и без него в конце программы. Подробнее про это написано здесь https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/590529/358371

Answer (score 0):

Как я уже говорил в комментариях,  если инициализация локальных статических переменных выбрасывает исключение, то обьект не будет создан, и говорить об освобождении памяти не приходится. Вот пример, поттверждающее это:

```
struct A {
    static int count;
    int n;
    A(const int k) : n(k) 
    { std::cout << "construct A" << ++count << std::endl; }
};
int A::count;
 int func(const int n) {
     if (n < 0)
         throw "error";
}

int main() {

    try {
        static A a1{ func(3) };
        static A a2{ func(-3) };
    }
    catch (const char* s)
    {
        std::cout << s;
    }
    return 0;
}
```